# Making a parseFloat only show one decimal

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I am trying to make it so when the user inputs a number and if they so happen to input the number and it has two or more decimals that it tells them that the number is invalid and should only be one decimal place and restates the prompt.

```js
const MIN = 0;
const MAX = 7;
gradeInput = parseFloat( prompt('Enter Grade for ' + codeInput + '') );
while( isNaN( gradeInput ) || gradeInput<MIN || gradeInput>MAX ) 
{
 alert('Your input was invalid');
 gradeInput = parseFloat(prompt('Enter Grade for ' + codeInput + ''));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [a regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in order to validate if the input looks correct. You can use the following pattern `^\d+(?:\.\d)?$` ([see it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qqSk5o/4))

```js
const regex = /^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/;

const wrongInput = "12.3.4";
const correctInput = "1.2";

console.log("is wrongInput valid?", regex.test(wrongInput));
console.log("is correctInput valid?", regex.test(correctInput));
```

The regular expression checks to see if the input is either numbers only or numbers, then a dot, then one more number.

So in your case, you would need to check if the supplied value is formatted correctly before parsing:

```js
const regex = /^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/;
let codeInput = "algebra"
let userGradeInput = prompt('Enter Grade for ' + codeInput + '');

while (!regex.test(userGradeInput)) { //if there is no match
  alert('Your input was invalid');
  userGradeInput = prompt('Enter Grade for ' + codeInput + '');
}

gradeInput = parseFloat(userGradeInput);

console.log(gradeInput)
```

This code doesn't do the other tests just to illustrate how to use the regex. To perform all checks on the input, you can have a separate function so you can easily reuse it:

```js
function isValid(input) {
  const MIN = 0;
  const MAX = 7;
  const regex = /^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/;
  
  if (regex.test(input)) { //only do the other checks if the input looks correct
    const parsedInput = parseFloat(input);
    
    return parsedInput > MIN && parsedInput < MAX; //check if it's within bounds
  } else {//it doesn't even look like a number
    return false; 
  }
}

let codeInput = "algebra"
gradeInput = prompt('Enter Grade for ' + codeInput + '');

while(!isValid(gradeInput)) {
  alert('Your input was invalid');
  gradeInput = parseFloat(prompt('Enter Grade for ' + codeInput + ''));
}

console.log(gradeInput)
```

Last note - the regex `/^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/` is a rather simplified one. I suspect this will be enough for your purposes, but I think it's worth explaining it. The regex will not allow other potentially valid inputs, for example `-2` or `+1.2` or `1.1e10` - these all can be correctly parsed into a JavaScript numeric format and could some could even be valid numbers for your code, but will be rejected by the rejex. For a more thorough floating point number regex, [check the brilliant writeup on the Regular-Expressions.info website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I put this into my script but it still makes a number valid for example 1.11 when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize you wanted a single number after the decimal point. I have amended my answer - the regex you want is `/^\d+(?:\.\d)?$/` for digits optionally followed by a dot and a single digit.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `gradeInput.toPrecision(1) === gradeInput` to validate the input

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: That doesn't really "validate" the input. *At best* it will fail any floating point numbers, when the intention is that they are allowed. However, it would also fail any double digit number, two - e.g. for `gradeInput = 10` calling `toPrecision(1)` will NOT be equal to the base. In reality, the suggestion as presented will fail **EVERY TIME** regardless of input, since `toPrecision` returns a string while `gradeInput` is a number, so `===` will return `false` because of the types mismatch.